# JWT + Spring security + Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, jwt

How to return JWT object without using controller. Because I am using loginprocessurl from spring security and it is not possible to use another controller for its form post 'action'..What is the solution ? I have watched video from javabrain about spring security and jwt but he is not using loginprocessingURL..

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: .loginPage("/memberarea.htm")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .usernameParameter("useremail")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/detail.htm")

Comment: This is what I did in websecurity configuration

Comment: I am trying to do like javabrain did (he was using controller for returning jwt)but while I am using loginprocessingurl and my form post action url in controller method has never used! (loginprocessingurl and form post action URL are same)

Comment: https://github.com/koushikkothagal/spring-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/io/javabrains/springsecurityjwt/SpringSecurityJwtApplication.java